# Installing Magento 2.4 in Linux Mint

Tags: installation, magento2.4, linux

I am trying to install Magento 2.4 in my localhost. I am using Linux Mint 19.1 as my OS. First I downloaded Magento 2.4 using below command.

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magentotest
```

I tried to install Magento 2.4 using below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magentotest/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magentotest --db-user=root --db-password=root \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
```

I am getting below error while trying to run above command.

`Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster`

[image]

I installed JDK and elastic search.

[image]

But I am getting below screen while trying to browse Magento 2.4

[image]

What is the solution ? How to install Magento 2.4 in Linux Mint ?

Answer (score 3):

You should change --elasticsearch-host=**es-host.example.com** to --elasticsearch-host=**localhost**

Elasticsearch for Magento `2.4.x` must be `7.x` version

Latest Elasticsearch version

[image]

Hope that it resolves your problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this video which help you into installation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y5OMAFLAZU

Comment: he is not asking how to install, the question where is the error ... and if you need to install composer project into folder directly, add dot at the end...

Answer (score 1):

Please try to enable elasticsearch

```
 sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
```

Then Start elasticsearch

```
 sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

See the status of elasticsearch service

```
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service
```